# Line graph in d3 rendering but not displaying

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to build a line graph using D3 (in a React app built with webpack and react-faux-dom) and have everything except the line(s) displaying. Checking the dev tools there is a path rendering, but it seems to be off screen to the right (hovering the path pops path.line 141523000000 x 742.33 up, right correct height for data and what appears to be UTC milliseconds for the width) and I'm not sure why.

The x-axis is a time scale

```
const x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(10).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%b %d, %Y'));
```

using

```
const parseTime = d3.timeParse('%Y-%m-%d');
```

for both the data

```
data.stocks.forEach((d) => {
  d.date = parseTime(d.date);
  d['GOOG'] = +d['GOOG'];
});
```

and the domain of the axis

```
x.domain(d3.extent(data.stocks, (d) => parseTime(d.date)));
```

If the x-axis is being set for a domain with numbers much smaller than the UTC milliseconds times I could the line being too far to the right to see on the chart, but they all convert with `parseTime()`  and the examples I've looked only use `d3.timeFormat()` so I haven't found the problem. Using a bunch of console logs it appears the data is getting through properly with

```
const valueline = d3.line()
  .x((d) => d.date)
  .y((d) => d['GOOG']);

svg.append('path')
  .data([data.stocks])
  .attr('class', 'line')
  .attr('d', valueline);
```

but I can't seem to change anything to get the lines on the chart. Anyone familiar with this and/or far more experienced with D3 to spot what's going on?

In case it's not glaringly obvious in the above, the full component is

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactFauxDOM from 'react-faux-dom';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

export default class StockChart extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const div = new ReactFauxDOM.Element('div');
    let stockMax;
    const rawData = this.props.data; // see below if needed
    const smallestDataSetSize = d3.min(rawData.map((stock) => stock.closingValues.length));
    const restrictingDataSet = rawData.filter((stock) => stock.closingValues.length === smallestDataSetSize)[0];
    const parseTime = d3.timeParse('%Y-%m-%d');
    const margin = {top: 20, right: 40, bottom: 70, left: 40}
    const width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
    const height = window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom - 75*2;
    const x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
    const y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
    const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(10).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%b %d, %Y'));
    const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5);

    // Get prelimiary data to set up chart
    stockMaximums = rawData.map((stock) => d3.max(stock.closingValues.map((d) => parseInt(d.price))));
    stockMax = d3.max(stockMaximums);

    // Fromat data into a JSON format that can be used with D3
    const data = { stocks: []};
    for (let i = smallestDataSetSize - 1; i > -1; i--) {
      const date = restrictingDataSet.closingValues[i].date;
      data.stocks.push({
        'date': date
      });
      rawData.map((stock) => {
        const stockData = stock.closingValues.filter((stockData) => stockData.date === date);
        data.stocks[data.stocks.length - 1][stock.name] = parseFloat(stockData[0].price);
      });
    }

    // Draw the plot
    let svg = d3.select(div).append('svg')
      .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr('height', height + margin.bottom + margin.top)
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

    x.domain(d3.extent(data.stocks, (d) => parseTime(d.date)));
    y.domain([0, stockMax*11/10]);

    svg.append('g')
      .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
      .call(xAxis)
      .selectAll('text')
        .style('text-anchor', 'end')
        .attr('dx', '-1rem')
        .attr('dy', '-.2rem')
        .attr('transform', 'rotate(-65)');

    svg.append('g')
      .call(yAxis);

    // Just trying one line right now while debugging
    const valueline = d3.line()
      .x((d) => d.date)
      .y((d) => d['GOOG']);

    data.stocks.forEach((d) => {
      d.date = parseTime(d.date);
      d['GOOG'] = +d['GOOG'];
    });

    svg.append('path')
      .data([data.stocks])
      .attr('class', 'line')
      .attr('d', valueline);

    return div.toReact();
  }
}
```

and the only CSS at the moment

```
.line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
}
```

with sample data

```
const rawData = {
    closingValues: [
        { date: "2018-09-28", price: "1193.4700" },
        { date: "2018-09-21", price: "1166.0900" },
        { date: "2018-09-14", price: "1172.5300" },
        { date: "2018-09-07", price: "1164.8300" },
        { date: "2018-08-31", price: "1218.1900" },
        { date: "2018-08-24", price: "1220.6500" },
        { date: "2018-08-17", price: "1200.9600" },
        { date: "2018-08-10", price: "1237.6100" },
        { date: "2018-08-03", price: "1223.7100" },
        { date: "2018-07-27", price: "1238.5000" },
        { date: "2018-07-20", price: "1184.9100" },
        { date: "2018-07-13", price: "1188.8200" },
        { date: "2018-07-06", price: "1140.1700" },
        { date: "2018-06-29", price: "1115.6500" },
        { date: "2018-06-22", price: "1155.4800" },
        { date: "2018-06-15", price: "1152.2600" },
        { date: "2018-06-08", price: "1120.8700" },
        { date: "2018-06-01", price: "1119.5000" },
        { date: "2018-05-25", price: "1075.6600" },
        { date: "2018-05-18", price: "1066.3600" },
        { date: "2018-05-11", price: "1098.2600" },
        { date: "2018-05-04", price: "1048.2100" },
        { date: "2018-04-27", price: "1030.0500" },
        { date: "2018-04-20", price: "1072.9600" },
        { date: "2018-04-13", price: "1029.2700" },
        { date: "2018-04-06", price: "1007.0400" },
        { date: "2018-03-29", price: "1031.7900" },
        { date: "2018-03-23", price: "1021.5700" },
        { date: "2018-03-16", price: "1135.7300" },
        { date: "2018-03-09", price: "1160.0400" },
        { date: "2018-03-02", price: "1078.9200" },
        { date: "2018-02-23", price: "1126.7900" },
        { date: "2018-02-16", price: "1094.8000" },
        { date: "2018-02-09", price: "1037.7800" },
        { date: "2018-02-02", price: "1111.9000" },
        { date: "2018-01-26", price: "1175.8400" },
        { date: "2018-01-19", price: "1137.5100" },
        { date: "2018-01-12", price: "1122.2600" },
        { date: "2018-01-05", price: "1102.2300" },
        { date: "2017-12-29", price: "1046.4000" },
        { date: "2017-12-22", price: "1060.1200" },
        { date: "2017-12-15", price: "1064.1900" },
        { date: "2017-12-08", price: "1037.0500" },
        { date: "2017-12-01", price: "1010.1700" },
        { date: "2017-11-24", price: "1040.6100" },
        { date: "2017-11-17", price: "1019.0900" },
        { date: "2017-11-10", price: "1028.0700" },
        { date: "2017-11-03", price: "1032.4800" },
        { date: "2017-10-27", price: "1019.2700" },
        { date: "2017-10-20", price: "988.2000" },
        { date: "2017-10-13", price: "989.6800" },
        { date: "2017-10-06", price: "978.8900" },
        { date: "2017-09-29", price: "959.1100" },
        { date: "2017-09-22", price: "928.5300" },
        { date: "2017-09-15", price: "920.2900" },
        { date: "2017-09-08", price: "926.5000" },
        { date: "2017-09-01", price: "937.3400" },
        { date: "2017-08-25", price: "915.8900" },
        { date: "2017-08-18", price: "910.6700" },
        { date: "2017-08-11", price: "914.3900" },
        { date: "2017-08-04", price: "927.9600" },
        { date: "2017-07-28", price: "941.5300" },
        { date: "2017-07-21", price: "972.9200" },
        { date: "2017-07-14", price: "955.9900" },
        { date: "2017-07-07", price: "918.5900" },
        { date: "2017-06-30", price: "908.7300" },
        { date: "2017-06-23", price: "965.5900" },
        { date: "2017-06-16", price: "939.7800" },
        { date: "2017-06-09", price: "949.8300" },
        { date: "2017-06-02", price: "975.6000" },
        { date: "2017-05-26", price: "971.4700" },
        { date: "2017-05-19", price: "934.0100" },
        { date: "2017-05-12", price: "932.2200" },
        { date: "2017-05-05", price: "927.1300" },
        { date: "2017-04-28", price: "905.9600" },
        { date: "2017-04-21", price: "843.1900" },
        { date: "2017-04-13", price: "823.5600" },
        { date: "2017-04-07", price: "824.6700" },
        { date: "2017-03-31", price: "829.5600" },
        { date: "2017-03-24", price: "814.4300" },
        { date: "2017-03-17", price: "852.1200" },
        { date: "2017-03-10", price: "843.2500" },
        { date: "2017-03-03", price: "829.0800" },
        { date: "2017-02-24", price: "828.6400" },
        { date: "2017-02-17", price: "828.0700" },
        { date: "2017-02-10", price: "813.6700" },
        { date: "2017-02-03", price: "801.4900" },
        { date: "2017-01-27", price: "823.3100" },
        { date: "2017-01-20", price: "805.0200" },
        { date: "2017-01-13", price: "807.8800" },
        { date: "2017-01-06", price: "806.1500" },
        { date: "2016-12-30", price: "771.8200" },
        { date: "2016-12-23", price: "789.9100" },
        { date: "2016-12-16", price: "790.8000" },
        { date: "2016-12-09", price: "789.2900" },
        { date: "2016-12-02", price: "750.5000" },
        { date: "2016-11-25", price: "761.6800" },
        { date: "2016-11-18", price: "760.5400" },
        { date: "2016-11-11", price: "754.0200" },
        { date: "2016-11-04", price: "762.0200" }
    ],
    id: "-LNgk1Gxv0RFmJbiYgnx",
    lastUpdated: "2018-09-28",
    name: "GOOG"
};
```

Comment: instead of `.data` use `.datum` or just `.attr('d', valueline(data.stocks))`

Comment: @rioV8 Both different approaches seem to render the same way unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem with the code is the use of the scales and the parsing of the data.

- best to do the parsing as soon as possible so you only have to do it once.
- apply the `x` and `y` scales in the calculation of the line

  ```
  const valueline = d3.line()
    .x((d) => x(d.date))
    .y((d) => y(d['GOOG']));
  ```

the whole code is (only the inner part because I used an HTML file to debug)

```
const smallestDataSetSize = d3.min(rawData.map((stock) => stock.closingValues.length));
const restrictingDataSet = rawData.filter((stock) => stock.closingValues.length === smallestDataSetSize)[0];
const parseTime = d3.timeParse('%Y-%m-%d');
let svgWidth = window.innerWidth;
let svgHeight = window.innerHeight - 75*2;
const margin = {top: 20, right: 40, bottom: 70, left: 40}
const width = svgWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
const height = svgHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;
const x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
const y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(10).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%b %d, %Y'));
const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5);

// Get prelimiary data to set up chart
var stockMaximums = rawData.map((stock) => d3.max(stock.closingValues.map((d) => parseInt(d.price))));
var stockMax = d3.max(stockMaximums);

// Fromat data into a JSON format that can be used with D3
const data = { stocks: []};
for (let i = smallestDataSetSize - 1; i > -1; i--) {
  const date = restrictingDataSet.closingValues[i].date;
  data.stocks.push({
    'date': date
  });
  rawData.map((stock) => {
    const stockData = stock.closingValues.filter((stockData) => stockData.date === date);
    data.stocks[data.stocks.length - 1][stock.name] = parseFloat(stockData[0].price);
  });
}

data.stocks.forEach((d) => {
  d.date = parseTime(d.date);
  d['GOOG'] = +d['GOOG'];
});

// Draw the plot
let svg = d3.select(div).append('svg')
  .attr('width', svgWidth)
  .attr('height', svgHeight)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

// x.domain(d3.extent(data.stocks, (d) => parseTime(d.date)));
x.domain(d3.extent(data.stocks, (d) => d.date));
y.domain([0, stockMax*11/10]);

svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'x axis')
  .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
  .call(xAxis)
  .selectAll('text')
    .style('text-anchor', 'end')
    .attr('dx', '-1rem')
    .attr('dy', '-.2rem')
    .attr('transform', 'rotate(-65)');

svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'y axis')
  .call(yAxis);

// Just trying one line right now while debugging
const valueline = d3.line()
  .x((d) => x(d.date))
  .y((d) => y(d['GOOG']));

svg.append('path')
  .attr('class', 'line')
  .attr('d', valueline(data.stocks));
```

Comment: @Alex why don't you sort the `restrictingDataSet.closingValues` based on `date` and then simply apply a `.map()` to convert to the data records with the 'GOOG' field

Comment: The data is always sorted when I fetch it, so with the full plot (with any number of lines) I have a forEach loop over rawData to create each line with a `.map()` over the data. I'm guessing this is the idea you have, but I wrote the single (debugging) example following another example online hoping that starting with something that did work would help me find what I had missing.

Comment: @Alex you are walking the array from end till start because the date is going backwards (??), the line does not mind if the `x` is descending

Comment: Oh, fair enough, the point is a point regardless of the order they are in. I was going backwards because the data is always fetched in reverse chronological order (and wanted it in chronological order, though as you mention that's not important). It's not end to start though, as not all of the stocks have the same amount of data, so I use the `smallestDataSetSize`, so the loop picks only the data where all the stocks have a closing price.